# Historical ship types

Tags: translation, learning

I need help with translating *historical ship types*. It's an easy thing to do when it's about things like *galleon* (*galiono*, right), but when it's about things like **catboat**, or **clipper** is a nightmare. I wonder, if there's some sort of list for such terms in *Esperanto*.

I'm mostly interested in XV-XVI century ships, but anything from the [list of ship types on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ship_types).

I just need terms for *catboat* and *clipper*.

Answer (score 1):

Mi ne scias ĉu ekzistas aŭtoritata listo por io tiel specifa, sed mi proponas du eblojn.

1. vidi kiel aliaj lingvoj solvis tion. Por `catboat` oni trovas rektan prunton de la tuta nomo, kiu verŝajne rezultus `katboato` aŭ adaptiĝon de la `cat` parton, ekzemple `Кэт` (`ket`) en la rusa, kiu tamen rilatas la velon pli ol la ŝipon.
2. menciinte la anglan nomon de la afero, uzi ĝiajn ĉefajn trajtojn por krei mallongan novan esperantlingvan nomon. Por `catboat` povus esti `unuvela unumasta`, aŭ `unumasta velŝipo` ekzemple. En kunteksto oni devus povi scii pri kio temas, sen bezoni detali ĉion (velo rektangula ne simetria, kun masto tute antaŭe, ktp.).

Por `clipper` rekta prunto estas plej ofta. En PIV ekzemple vi trovos la vorton [klipero](https://vortaro.net/#klipero_kd): *Rapida, multetonela velŝipo.*

Comment: Mi ne pensas ke "katboato" estas akceptebla, ĉar tiu speco de ŝipo ne rilatas al kato.

Comment: @GrégoireC  `kataro` rilatas nek katon, nek aron ... `klipero` rilatas nek klipon nek eron ... [PMEG - ŝajnaj kunmetaĵoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/shajnkunmetajhoj.html)

Comment: Mi scias ke tiaj vortoj ekzistas. Oni devas eviti ilin.